# NativeScript StackLayout Problems - How do set percentages to width and height?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to design a simple layout, using STACKLAYOUT. I want the layout to be four sections, as in the following crudely made image:

[image: Layout]

## 1 , the header will be 75px height, 100% width.

## 2 , the footer also 75px, 100% width

## 3 #4, both these will be 50% of the remaining space.

**My Non-Functioning Code**

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="100%" height="50%"
            backgroundColor="lightgray">
            <Label text="Label 1" backgroundColor="red"
                horizontalAlignment="stretch" height="75"/>
            <Label text="Label 3" 
                backgroundColor="green" />
            <Label text="Label 4"
                backgroundColor="blue" />
            <Label text="Label 2"  height="75"
                backgroundColor="yellow" horizontalAlignment="stretch" />
        </StackLayout>
```

So, to clarify, I want the header at top, footer at bottom, and the remaining middle space equally divided.

Can anyone help me out please? I have tried so many combinations of the above code, and still it never displays properly.

Thanks for checking out this question.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with GridLayout here, you really don't want to stack the items but split the space accordingly for all items, so try

```
<GridLayout rows="75,*,*,75" backgroundColor="lightgray">
    <Label row="0" text="Label 1" backgroundColor="red" />
    <Label row="1" text="Label 3" backgroundColor="green" />
    <Label row="2" text="Label 4" backgroundColor="blue" />
    <Label row="3" text="Label 2" backgroundColor="yellow" />
</GridLayout>
```